# I want multiple URLs to point to a single .aspx site and be able to determine what data to show based on the URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

The site is currently hosted on a shared Windows server using HSphere. My initial thought was to do a masked redirect at my registrar to a "main" url and detect the Request.UrlReferrer, however that seems to be a little hit or miss and if I pass a parameter to the multiple urls it gets lost.

```
If Session("SiteId") Is Nothing Then
   If IsNothing(Request.UrlReferrer) Then
        Session("SiteId") = 1000
    Else
        Dim strReferrer As String = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
        Session("SiteId") = objSiteFunctions.getSiteIdByUrl(strReferrer)
    End If
 End If
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're doing, but why aren't you just using the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host (or Path) object? UrlReferrer will only be populated for cross-domain requests I believe.

Comment: @Ian Basically i have mainsite.com, site2.com, and site3.com, to the end user they are completely separate sites but in reality is one set of pages and database. The only way I know to achieve this is to have site2 & 3 "masked redirect" at the registrar, but as mentioned, that has some issues.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't think you would be able to mask a redirect between different domains, I think url rewriting can only apply within the same domain right? Also, if you are trying to access the session state from a request with a different URL it probably won't work, because of the same-origin policies applied to cookies that the browser sends, and your session ID will be in a cookie if your using standard forms auth. You can send cookies to different subdomains though. Sounds like you should be storing this info on the client if it can be insecure.

Comment: @Ian Other than losing the query string and parameters the current situation mostly works on my Win 10 computer in chrome & firefox. Edge is a bit iffy. I'm told that it doesn't work at all on a Win 7 computer... I'm wondering if there is a different approach completely, maybe some URL/Domain configuration on HSPhere... unfortunately my web host's support is next to useless.

Comment: It might just be working because you are using localhost urls on your dev machine. Have you actually setup your dev machine so that you can use realistic URLs?

Comment: @Ian yes, it is using live URLs and the site is hosted on a shared server.

Comment: I would try using something like a concurrent static dictionary instead of the session state and then stick id's into a hidden field (or send them in an ajax request) that gets submitted. I think the session state assumes a single domain, but any static object declared in your ASP.NET app will be accessible everywhere. If you're just doing a small scale site it will work. Just make sure you handle the case where enterprising (or evil) user tries changing their own ID on the client side (i.e. - someone shouldn't be able to become a super admin by just setting that field value to 1).

Comment: @Ian I think I sorted it out! Using domain aliasing in my host's control panel and pointing the domains to the name servers for those aliases rather than redirecting. After I did that, I simply changed the "UrlReferrer" to "Url" and it appears to be working exactly as I hoped.